# php echo to "html page"

Tags: php, echo

Today's predicament is in the form of php.This 'send_contact' script is pretty basic stuff really, however, as opposed to simply echo a message.we'd like to echo or redirect to a lovely styled html page.

```
    <?php
    // Contact Subject
    $fullname = $_POST["full_name"];
    // Details
    $businessname = $_POST["business_name"];
    $addressline1 = $_POST["address_line_1"];


    //HTML email
    $headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
    $headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=iso-8859-1" . "\r\n";
    // Mail of Sender
    $mail_from = $_POST["email_addr"];
    //From
    $headers .="from: <".$mail_from.">";

    //Enter your email address
    $to ="mywifelovesphp@php.co.uk";
    $subject = "Catalogue Request - ".date("d/m/Y");
    $message = "<html> <body>";
    $message .= "<h3>".$businessname."</h3>\r\n";
    $message .= $fullname."\r\n";
    $message .= $addressline1."\r\n";
    $message .= "</body></html>";

    $send_contact=mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);


    //Check, if message sent to your email
    //display message "We've recieved your information"
    if($send_contact)
    {echo "We've recieved your information";
    }
else {
echo "Error";
}   
    ?>
```

Comment: What's the question again?

Comment: So replace `"We've recieved your information"` with a lovely, styled HTML document.

Comment: Why don't you send with phpmailer? You don't have to work with headers and it would work on different mail servers without the need hacking it

Comment: Hi, and thanks for your comment. To put the question more clearly, the question is actually 'how to echo' to a html page...

Comment: Do you want the `echo` to show in a html page or to generate a html file?

Comment: You can put **PHP in HTML** rather than **HTML in PHP**. Get the thought?

Comment: Hi Sergio, thank you for your comment. We are looking to generate an html file...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can Echo a style within a tag . I tried creating a class in the header section if you echo a tag with a class the class will inherit. It works for me here is an example . Just Remove the "" . It will show!

```
      echo "<p style=color:blue;margin-left:20px;>We've recieved your information</p>"
```